# how can I do a POST Req for a REST service in SoapUI 5.1.2 with form-data

Tags: rest, post, soapui, multipartform-data

Could you help me to resolved the problem that I have?

Using Postman (REST Client - chrome extension) I do a Post to a REST service an I get the correct answer from the services. 
The answer is "201  Created" and a new row is added into the DB.

URL  = http://suring-t.suremptec.com.ar/gis/13/rest/1.0/organizations

form-date =     metadata

```
    {
        "meta" : {
            "version" : "1.0",
            "description" : "Organization"
        },
        "id" : null,
        "name" : "test org",
        "startDate" : "2014-06-05 16:20:31.334",
        "endDate" : null,
        "administrable" : true,
        "published" : true,
        "href" : "\/2\/rest\/1.0\/organizations\/1"
    }
```

I can't find the way to make SoapUI (5.1.2) works with the same request.

URL  = http://suring-t.suremptec.com.ar/gis/13/rest/1.0/organizations

form-date =
    metadata
        {
            "meta" : {
                "version" : "1.0",
                "description" : "Organization"
            },
            "id" : null,
            "name" : "test org",
            "startDate" : "2014-06-05 16:20:31.334",
            "endDate" : null,
            "administrable" : true,
            "published" : true,
            "href" : "/2/rest/1.0/organizations/1"
        }

The response is "200 - Ok" but

Any Ideas, how should configure the soapui request?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started [Getting started with REST](http://www.soapui.org/rest-testing/getting-started.html)